# Coding convention for empty functions that need to be overridden in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, convention

Accourding to the very short [Coding Conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html) there is no answer for the opimal way of writing down empty functions in Kotlin.

Example:

```
ani.setAnimationListener(object: Animation.AnimationListener {

    override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) = Unit
    override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {}

    override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) =
        activity.runOnUiThread { loadLists() }
})
```

Here only one of the 3 necessary Methods of AnimationListener (Android) is used.

Which type of empty Method should be used?
[Single Expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#single-expression-functions) (`fun name() = Unit`) or the traditional way used in Java (`fun name() {}`)?

I personally like the `= Unit`-Way more because that seems to be meant the way of shorting functions down to one line. But `{}` is shorter yet older and probably more ugly.

And is there any better/shorter way for doing this code?

Comment: You've used the `coding-style` tag, but it says: _DO NOT USE! This tag refers to an entirely opinionated subject and is therefore no longer on-topic_.  That would suggest that this question is therefore off-topic.

Comment: I removed the tag.

Comment: Your question remains one of coding _style_, which is off-topic for Stack Overflow these days.  You might try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've added link to [Coding Conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html) where seems like actually there is an answer to your question

> Unit
>
> If a function returns Unit, the return type should be omitted:
>
> fun foo() { // ": Unit" is omitted here
>
> }

So I believe

```
fun foo() {}
```

or

```
fun foo() {
}
```

should be the answer

Comment: I wanted to create such empty implementation as just a convenience to use callbacks that have many functions in them that I don't care about. But when I do use one, it always calls "super". Is there a way to avoid it?